# Revoke token with identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, bearer-token

Im trying to revoke token using identity server 4, i have only bearer token in my part of code, the problem is that i should use  RevokeTokenAsync method, but this take more parameters tha ihave available :

```
public async void Logout(string bearerToken)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();

  // request token revocation
  var response = await client.RevokeTokenAsync(new TokenRevocationRequest
      {
        Address = uri,           
        ClientId = clientId,    // ?
        ClientSecret = key,     // ?
        Token = bearerToken
      });
   // manage errors ....      
}
```

Exist any other way to revocate the token without passing others parameters besides token?

Comment: The bearerToken parameter suggests that you want to revoke a JWT access token. But that is not possible. Only certain tokens can be revoked: access tokens (reference tokens only) and refresh token, as [documented](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/revocation.html). A client can't 'destroy' an access token. At most it can 'forget' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling IdentityServer's endpoints, you should be authenticated for IdentityServer. So you have to pass those parameter with your request.

No there is not any way for calling revoke endpoint without ClientId and ClientSecret.

You can find your ClientId and ClientSecret in your IdentityServer's configuration.